# PopupMenu with checkboxes

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, popup

I am trying to create a popup menu where I can check some boxes to create some plots after the calculation. It is like multiple selections popupmenu. 
My Frankenstein version, of course, isn't working.

```
PopupMenu["a", {Row[{"a", Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFa], {False, True}]}], 
Row[{"b", Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFb], {False, True}]}], 
Row[{"c", Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFc], {False, True}]}], 
Row[{"d", Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFd], {False, True}]}]}]
```

Any suggestion or solutions? :)

Comment: How wedded are you to this being a `PopupMenu`? It is possible to do, but requires some cleverness and trickery and will not be entirely robust. A better solution, to my eyes, is to use `DialogInput` to allow your user to pick their settings and then use `Dynamic` to display the settings. This affords you greater robustness and control.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a little solution using the undocumented `AttachCell`:

```
fakePopupMenu1[
   label_,
   HoldPattern[Dynamic[var_, e___]],
    selections_,
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  DynamicModule[{attached},
   Button[
    PopupMenu[label, {label}, ops],
    If[! MatchQ[attached, _CellObject] || 
      NotebookRead[attached] === $Failed,
     (attached =
       FrontEndExecute@
        FrontEnd`AttachCell[
         EvaluationBox[],
         Cell[
          (* Make selector form *)
          BoxData@
           ToBoxes@
            Panel@
             Grid[
              Append[

               Map[{Row@{#, ": "}, Checkbox[Dynamic[var[#], e]]} &, 
                selections],
               {Null, Null, 
                DefaultButton["Done", NotebookDelete@EvaluationCell[]]}
               ],
              Alignment -> Left
              ],
          Background -> White
          ],
         {Offset[{0, 0}, 0], {Left, Top}},
         {Left, Top},
         "ClosingActions" -> {"OutsideMouseClick"}
         ]
      )
     ],
    Appearance ->
     {
      "Default" -> None,
      "Hover" -> None,
      "Pressed" -> None
      }
    ]
   ];
fakePopupMenu1[
  label_,
   selections_,
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 DynamicModule[{var = <||>}, 
  fakePopupMenu1[label, Dynamic[var], selections, ops]]
```

When we use it we get a little popup like this (note that I changed the positioning `Top` to `Bottom` for this):

```
fakePopupMenu1["Choose, yo", Dynamic[var, Echo], {1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

And since it just takes a `Dynamic` spec as usual if you click on any of those checkbox boxes it will echo `True` with the tag `var[1]` (i.e. it calls `f[True, var[sel]]` for `f` in the second argument of `Dynamic`)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get what you need is to use the following:

```
TabView[{
  "a" -> Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFa], {False, True}],
  "b" -> Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFb], {False, True}], 
  "c" -> Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFc], {False, True}], 
  "d" -> Checkbox[Dynamic[fpTFd], {False, True}]
  }]
```

Of course, it is not PopupMenu but it is compact enough and intuitively understandable.